# web3 balanceOf always 0

Tags: ethereum, solidity, web3js

I'm trying to get the balance of an address on my smart contract using web3, but the balance is always 0. Using metamask on Rinkeby since my contract is deployed on rinkeby. https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x8e3a88be716ce7c8119c36558ec97bc634592255

You can verify the wallet has a balance by putting it in the balanceOf function on etherScan. Use the address 0x8b54A82a12bD5A7bA33B4842cA677E55f78a8612

```js
let provider = web3.currentProvider;
web3 = new Web3(provider);
let abi = 'too long of a string to post here';
let MyContract = web3.eth.contract(JSON.parse(abi));
let myContractInstance = MyContract.at('0x8e3a88be716ce7c8119c36558ec97bc634592255');
let address = '0x8b54A82a12bD5A7bA33B4842cA677E55f78a8612';

function balanceOf(address) {
    if (!address) {
        return;
    }

    this.myContractInstance.balanceOf.call(address, function(error, balance) {
      if (error) {
        return;
      }

      alert(balance.c[0] + ' RHC');
    });
}

balanceOf(address);
```

Here is the getBalance function on my contract

```js
function balanceOf(address _owner) public view returns (uint256 balance) {
    return balances[_owner];
}
```

Website implemented on http://robinhoodcoin.net/metamask.html

Code https://github.com/robinhoodcoin/robinhoodcoin.github.io/blob/master/metamask.html

When I change the provider to be the following:

```js
var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://rinkeby.infura.io/'));
```

I am able to get the balance. SO there is something up with using metamask as the provider.

Comment: Did you perhaps not have MetaMask pointing at Rinkeby?

Comment: yeah I tested both rinkeby and mainnet using metamask

Comment: The website you linked to seems to be broken; it gives an error because `ropsten` is an undeclared variable.

Comment: yup I only have rinkeby and mainnet setup.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misread.

Comment: This line looks wrong: `self.myContractInstance = self.MyContract.at(self.address);`. It should read `self.MyContract.at(self.contractAddress);`, right?

Comment: omg. I'm an idiot. that worked

Comment: BTW, you want `balance.toString()`, not `balance.c[0]`. `web3.js` gives you a `BigNumber` instance when a return value is numeric. You can call `toNumber()` on it, but be careful about the loss of precision (which is why `BigNumber` is used in the first place). For display purposes, `toString()` will always give you a full precision result.

Comment: thanks for all your help! My app never complained about this.address so I overlooked it. also switching to not use BigNumber

Comment: This appears to be based on code not in the question, and now the link that contained it is dead, making this not reproducible / lacking a [MCVE].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line at https://github.com/robinhoodcoin/robinhoodcoin.github.io/blob/master/metamask.html#L118 has a typo. It reads:

```
self.myContractInstance = self.MyContract.at(self.address);
```

but the address is stored at `self.contractAddress`, so it should read:

```
self.myContractInstance = self.MyContract.at(self.contractAddress);
```

After making that fix, the page works fine for me with MetaMask.